# cascading-parquet throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cascading

Trying to run this code

Main.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
..
Properties properties = new Properties();
AppProps.setApplicationJarClass(properties, Main.class);
HadoopFlowConnector flowConnector = new HadoopFlowConnector(properties);

Scheme sourceScheme = new queries.ParquetTupleScheme(new Fields("a", "b", "c"));
Tap inTap = new Hfs(sourceScheme, inPath);
...
...
...
}
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cascading/scheme/Scheme
```

Here is what i tried so far

1. When I replace this:

   `Scheme sourceScheme = new ParquetTupleScheme(new Fields("a", "b",
   "c"));`

   with this:

   `Scheme sourceScheme = null;`

   the error goes away
2. When I'm creating class that extends `Scheme<JobConf, RecordReader, OutputCollector, Object[], Object[]>` like `ParquetTupleScheme`
   the error goes away
3. When I'm trying to check if this is a specific parquet-cascading error

   `Object a = new PigCombiner()`

   the error goes away

I'm using :

- cascading 2.5.1
- parquet-cascading 1.3.0
- hadoop-core 1.2.1

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you paste the whole stack track and tell which line throws this exception?

Comment: Scheme sourceScheme = new queries.ParquetTupleScheme(new Fields("a", "b", "c")); does....

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem before. As far as I know, this problem stems from missing cascading Scheme.class in your classpath, thereby throwing this exception during the runtime.

In order to resolve this, you should include the cascading-core-2.5.1.jar into your hadoop classpath by using **'export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/jar_directory/cascading-core-2.5.1.jar'**. You could use **'hadoop classpath'** to check whether the jar is properly included.

This is my debut in stackoverflow. :)